# Installing aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, terminal, pip, command-line-interface

I am getting this message when I try to install aws. Anyone have any ideas of what's going on?

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 725, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 756, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 266, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-TIuiKe-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

The command I'm using is pip install awscli

Comment: try ``sudo pip install awscli`` instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about permisson. The installer are trying to write in a folder that doesnt have permission.

try `sudo pip install awscli`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is trying to uninstall six-1.4.1. I had the same issue. Telling pip to ignore installed package should work.

```
sudo pip install --ignore-installed awscli
```

Answer (score 0):

**sudo pip install --upgrade --user awscli**

**--upgrade** : tells pip to upgrade any requirements that are already installed